# how to split by multiple columns when using multidplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, multidplyr

**tl;dr**
How do I make "partition" from multiplyr split on multiple columns?

**Motivation:**
I was unhappy with using 1 of 32 cores for hard-working summarize, so I am trying to use [multi-dplyer](https://github.com/hadley/multidplyr/blob/master/vignettes/multidplyr.Rmd)  I am operating on multiple columns.

**Example:**
The vignette shows grouping by a single column, but when I do that, my other grouping column is not considered.

**Code:**

```
library(dplyr)
library(multidplyr)
library(nycflights13)

flights1 <- partition(flights, flight)
flights2 <- summarise(flights1, dep_delay = mean(dep_delay, na.rm = TRUE))
flights3 <- collect(flights2)
```

So how about splitting on year, month, and day?

**This doesn't work for me:**

```
flights1 <- partition(flights, list(year, month, day))
flights2 <- summarise(flights1, dep_delay = mean(dep_delay, na.rm = TRUE))
flights3 <- collect(flights2)
```

I can't seem to make this work.  Can you point to a proper or at least effective way to do this?

Comment: I think you should open an issue on git-hub.

Comment: Does `partition(flights, year, month, day)` work for you?

Comment: It might... I'm waiting for the processing to continue to see what my columns are upon "collect".

Comment: @WeihuangWong - it seems to be working.  Thank you!  Can you make it into an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to `?partition`,  the usage for `partition` is

> `partition(.data, ..., cluster = get_default_cluster())`

where `...` are variables to partition by. Instead of passing in a list of variables, pass in each variable separately, i.e.

```
partition(flights, year, month, day)
```